# OpenLiteSpeed Poor Performance and SSL handshake failed(5)

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, ssl, openlitespeed

I am using OpenLiteSpeed + Wordpress + LiteSpeed Cache (https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/openlitespeed-wordpress). I don't know why the performance is terrible. Also, when I do load tests, many "SSL handshake failed (5)" errors appear. For the SSL certificate, I got it from Let's Encrypt. Any suggestion? Thanks.

OpenLiteSpeed  [httpd_config.conf](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/john916zhang/de57d8c4e13850650366e7bf7260a867/raw/292c8280a4ea91f83ded63a4b80931b720e28f5d/gistfile1.txt)

[image: load test]

CPU is idle most of the time.

[image: top]

Comment: what was ab command you did ?

Comment: I used h2load, please see the images above.

Comment: where is error message ? h2load says 0 fail 0 error

Comment: You see. Only 10 requests each second. It is too slow.

Comment: is that dynamic request or cached static request?   by default OLS limits PHP max connection to 10

Comment: Yes, it is a cached request.

Comment: try test a static resources , see how it behaves.

Comment: For a public network benchmark environment, 850 requests per second are not really bad. May I know where you ran the h2load? Was it from the same zone/region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your test client issue. Please prepare your client-server in the same area to avoid any network latency issue. For example, I launched a California node and run the same benchmark command, and the result is **8** times faster than yours.

`h2load -n 100000 -c 100 -t 1 -T 5 -m 10 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'`

```
https://www.gospel4china.org/

starting benchmark...

spawning thread #0: 100 total client(s). 100000 total requests

TLS Protocol: TLSv1.3

Cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Server Temp Key: X25519 253 bits

Application protocol: h2

progress: 10% done

progress: 20% done

progress: 30% done

progress: 40% done

progress: 50% done

progress: 60% done

progress: 70% done

progress: 80% done

progress: 90% done

progress: 100% done



finished in 13.83s, 7232.49 req/s, 218.66MB/s

requests: 100000 total, 100000 started, 100000 done, 100000 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 errored, 0 timeout

status codes: 100000 2xx, 0 3xx, 0 4xx, 0 5xx

traffic: 2.95GB (3170223982) total, 1.16MB (1219082) headers (space savings 99.47%), 2.95GB (3165400000) data

                     min         max         mean         sd        +/- sd

time for request:      536us       3.65s    113.50ms    195.50ms    89.74%

time for connect:    14.72ms     87.00ms     49.23ms     18.02ms    63.00%

time to 1st byte:    74.08ms    114.00ms     89.39ms     10.21ms    59.00%

req/s           :      72.34      132.13       88.26        9.67    79.00%
```

FYI, for such server/network issues, please post in serverfault next time.